# Snowpark Python procedure errors when calling a Javascript procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are starting to use Snowpark Python more to make the switch, but at times we would like to call Javascript procedures that have not been converted yet from a Snowpark Python procedure. In general that works, but if the Javascript does anything like `alter session set QUERY_TAG = 'something'` sometimes `USE SCHEMA` the process errors saying unsupported.

Does anyone know if this is by design, or if there is something I can do to make these work.  The other weird part is that if I write the Use Role and what not in Python it works fine.

`call utility.procedure.Test_Python();`

```
create or replace procedure utility.procedure.Test_Python() returns string
    language PYTHON RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.10' 
    handler = 'main' PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python') as
$$
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session):
    session.call("UTILITY.END_USER_INPUT_PROCEDURE.Test_Javascript")
$$
```

```
create or replace procedure utility.procedure.Test_Javascript() returns VARCHAR
    language javascript
    execute as caller as
$$
    snowflake.execute({sqlText: 'use role REPORT_ANALYST;'})
    snowflake.execute({sqlText: 'use warehouse REPORT_WH_XS;'})
    snowflake.execute({sqlText: 'USE SCHEMA END_USER_INPUT.REPORT_ANALYST;'})
$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Accessing and Setting the Session State](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights#accessing-and-setting-the-session-state)

> If a caller’s rights stored procedure makes changes to the session, those changes can persist after the end of the CALL. **Owner’s rights stored procedures are not permitted to change session state.**

`USE SCHEMA/ROLE/WAREHOUSE` changes the session state and `utility.procedure.Test_Python()` is executed as owner.

To execute this procedure as caller it should be altered:

```
create or replace procedure utility.procedure.Test_Python() returns string
    language PYTHON RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.10' 
    handler = 'main' PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python') 
    execute as caller 
as
...
```

Comment: Didnt think about that being execute as owner by default for some reason.  Thanks this works perfectly